# What is the 'periodic table' tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is [periodic-table](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/periodic-table) intended for? The tag wiki excerpt is not very helpful as it just describes what the periodic table is.

> The periodic table is a systematic arrangement of the known chemical elements in order of atomic number. The elements are arranged in groups on the basis of similarity in chemical and physical properties.

I consistently find myself retagging [periodic-table](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/periodic-table) questions (about 90) with [periodic-trends](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/periodic-trends) (about 80) which is usually a more appropriate tag (example [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37424/why-do-some-elements-such-as-polonium-not-follow-the-trend-of-decreasing-atomic)) although a sizeable number of questions have both tags (about 30).

To me it seems that the tag should be about the layout/history/interpretation etc. of the periodic table, rather than being used as a duplicate of [periodic-trends](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/periodic-trends) (for example [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/901/what-are-the-alternatives-to-the-periodic-table-of-the-elements)).

Can we agree on a scope for this tag and write a better tag wiki (and maybe then gradually remove it from inappropriate questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am very much for this suggestion. Unfortunately it has to be done manually, there is no mechanism to do it silently and fast (like a merge).

You can start by rewriting the tag wiki pages, and just remove it from the questions where it does not belong.

As usual, I suggest leaving the negative scoring questions untouched (if there are any). If they seem to be abandoned (no answers or low scoring answers) we could probably think about removing them altogether.

Comment: How does one go about removing questions? Should I flag them for moderator attention? What are the criteria for determining whether a question should be removed?

Comment: @bon According to [this meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/271002), _dead questions_ are automatically deleted after 30 days, _abandoned questions_ after 365 days, and _abandoned closed questions_ after 9 days. Therefore it is usually not necessary to [flag abandoned questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236354/271002). Just vote to close or vote down as appropriate.